# Terminology: Are a first-order filter and a single-pole filter always the same thing and completely interchangeable?

Tags: filter

Or, asked another way:

1. Is it possible to create a single-pole filter that isn't a
   first-order filter?
2. Is it possible to create a first-order filter that isn't
   single-pole?

Does this also apply for second-order vs double-pole, and third-order, etc.?

Comment: What about zeroes -- should a "single pole" filter be all-pole, do the zeroes not matter, what if the zeroes are higher order..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: All first order filters have a single pole and vice versa. The order of a system comes from the order of the differential equation that describes the system. Converting that to Laplace domain, then extracting the transfer function reveals the pole.

1st order DE:$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}+ay(t)=Ku(t) \tag{1}$$
Converts via the Laplace transformation to:
$$sY(s)+aY(s)=KU(s)$$ for zero initial conditions.

Extracting the transfer function:
$$G(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}=\frac{K}{s+a}$$
thus revealing the pole \$p=-a\$ which is the value of \$s\$ that makes \$G(s)=\infty \$.

This can be extended to higher order filters as well.

UPDATE:

The order of a differential equation is the highest order derivative in the differential equation which in this case is of the state variable, which is shown on the left of the equals sign in equation 1.

EDIT FOR @Tony Stewart EE75:

Consider the DE:
$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}+ay(t)=K\frac{du(t)}{dt}+Kbu(t) \tag{2}$$
The order of equation 2 is obtained from the highest order derivative of the state variable.

The differential expression on the right is causal signal (or 2) of the independent variable (t) that can influence the state of the filter, but does not influence the characterization of the order of the filter in this case.

Converting via the Laplace transformation to:
$$sY(s)+aY(s)=KsU(s)+KbU(s)$$ for zero initial conditions.

Extracting the transfer function:
$$G(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}=K\frac{s+b}{s+a}$$
thus revealing the pole \$p=-a\$

The characteristic polynomial in the denominator exactly corresponds to the left hand side of the differential equation when put into standard form. So the order of the filter can also be determined by the highest degree of \$s\$ in the characteristic polynomial.

Granted, the zero in the numerator will provide responses that approximate the response of a lower order filter for some values of \$s\$. Regardless, the order is based on the degree of s in the characteristic polynomial.

**Update:**

The following is a demonstration of the invariance of a pole and the variability of the zeros. This will demonstrate several transfer functions based on the same circuit. Because the circuit remains the same for each transfer function, the characteristic polynomial is invariant except perhaps by a multiplier.
Figure one shows a circuit with two capacitors and two resistors.

First define \$R=R_{1}+R_{2}\$ and \$\frac{1}{C}=\frac{1}{C_{1}}+\frac{1}{C_{2}}\$

The transfer functions can easily be found using the voltage divider rule.

From Figure 1:

\$\frac{V_{ac}}{Vs}=\frac{R_{1}}{R}\frac{s+\frac{1}{R_{1}C_{1}}}{s+\frac{1}{RC}}\$, \$\frac{V_{ce}}{Vs}=\frac{R_{2}}{R}\frac{s+\frac{1}{R_{2}C_{2}}}{s+\frac{1}{RC}}\$, \$\frac{V_{bd}}{Vs}=\frac{\frac{1}{RC}}{s+\frac{1}{RC}}\$

From Figure 2:

\$\frac{V_{bd}}{Vs}=\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{RC}}\$

Clearly the denominators in every transfer function are the same. Why? Because the circuit has not changed. Yes Vs moved but is still in series. Impedance-wise Vs is a short so moving it to different places will not affect the results.

So \$(s+\frac{1}{RC})=0\$ is called the characteristic equation obtained from the homogeneous differential equation which has order 1.

This is where the filter's order comes from and the zero's have nothing to do with it. It works for higher order systems too.

The zeros effect the shape of the frequency response. When used in feedback control systems, zeros can calm down oscillations, or make them worse. Care must be taken.

The TF from Figure 2 is clearly a high pass filter, the third TF from Figure one is a low pass filter.

The first two from Figure 1 are like high pass filters, but have a constant gain below a corner frequency.

So my answer remains the same, "All first order filters have a single pole and vice versa."

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGzVXx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To be fair, the control system folks can use zero-pole cancellation techniques to "reduce the order" of a system to improve performance or stability. The cancellation is never perfect so the order of the system remains the same, but the response of the system is closer to that of a lower order. This raises the the concept of fractional derivatives. Fractional derivatives might be used to make a fractional order DE, then the previous discussion will take a different twist.

L and C are defined with integer order derivatives. This is physics, not invention. So if anyone has a the ability to go down this road then please post an answer.

Comment: Explain the order of the filter $$G(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}=K\frac{s+b}{s+a}$$

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75: Thank you. Please read my edit

Comment: Possibly something less than 1st order meaning towards a 0 order filter with 2 caps

Comment: Thanks. Are you also able to answer Tim Williams' question he added as a comment to my initial question: "What about zeroes -- should a "single pole" filter be all-pole, do the zeroes not matter, what if the zeroes are higher order..?"

Comment: @user1596274: Zeros change based on where the output us taken from a system. The poles occur from the solutions to the characteristic polynomial, which does **not** change based on where the output is taken. All poles and zeros are essentially first degree/order. We could have a discussion on whether degree or order is correct when referring to poles and zeros. Systems with more zeros than zeros than poles are often compensated to make them strictly proper. An example of an improper filter is the PID compensator. It is 1st order and has two zeros and one pole as a free integrator.

Comment: I will add an update to my answer with a demonstration. But not right away

Answer (score 0):

Answers:1 no, 2 no, 3 yes

- filters store energy and represent each "reactor" by an order s or 1/s.

The number of reactances determines the order of the filter or power in the Taylor series.

This ignores extra values in series or in shunt with a single equivalent value.

- The output of a zero order system is proportional to the input. At all times, the output is equal to the input multiplied by some constant of proportionality.
- In closed loop servo Control Systems , this is the most ideal stable design , so compensation near the 0 deg phase margin or unity gain is designed to reduce the order from 2 or more to 1 or 0 order in there band.
- One such comp. is called a Lead-Lag RC filter or simple series R//C to shunt R+C to compensate for another integrator in the loop and reduce the order in one f region.
- But if you remember in future that if you want the most stable servo
  , use proportional feedback for each order on each control parameter
  e.g. position, velocity, and acceleration.

If you try to use acceleration to control velocity with integration that adds -1 order and subtracts 90 degrees out of 180 degrees of zero order negative feedback phase margin.